# Copy file from bundle to SDCard in Android

Tags: android

I want to copy a raw file from assets to the SD card. I have found lots of suggestions of how to do it (using AssetsManager, FileInputStream, etc) and I have successfully managed to do it.

But my problem is that all solutions I found depend on having "context".

I want a way to copy a file without having any restrictions as I am trying to build a library that requires moving files from internal memory to the external one.

I hope there is a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my problem is that all solutions I found depend on having "context".

The only way to access an asset is by way of an `AssetManager`, and the only way to get an `AssetManager` involves a `Context`.

> I hope there is a way to do this

No, sorry.